# How can you change the URL of a business page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

How can you change the URL of a business page on facebook? I looked in page info and page settings everywhere to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'd like my current business page URL (https://www.facebook.com/tenfourWest-118465346274092/) to be changed to: https://www.facebook.com/tenfourWest if possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please consult their Help section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to facebook using your account as admin of the facebook page.
2. Go to your facebook page.
3. Look for the "About" Section on the right side. (It was located above "Page Transparency")
4. Click "See All".
5. Under "General", look for the username and click "Edit".
6. From @tenfourWest-118465346274092 to @tenfourWest.(Make sure this username does not exist. Just follow the tips on Choosing a username.)
7. Click "Create Username".

Done...

Hope this will work.

Comment: I cant tell you how long I looked for that darn username. You pointing me towards looking in the ABOUT section was crucial... it's hidden there. THANKS!

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Try the other way on how to find the ABOUT section. I have a new answer below :)